# Get items inside special characters

Tags: c#

What I mean in my question is, I am attempting to create a basic scripting program. I want it to choose a random word from a select inputted words.

I.E:

```
Hello {you,uyo,u}, whats up?
```

it will then randomly select from one of the ones in brackets to output something like:

```
Hello u, whats up?/Hello you, whats up?/Hello uyo, whats up?
```

Heres what Ive attempted thus far:
[image]

Please excuse any bad code, This is my first time attempting to script.
The program looks like this:
[image: Second img]

The program works thus far, but I cannot put anything else in the message but the scramble{}, I want to just be able to throw {} anywhere and it would randomly choose.

Comment: Why don't you copy-paste your code here, instead of making a screenshot???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want ot consider regular expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "Hello {you,uyo,u}, whats {up,down}?";
        var random = new Random();
        var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"{.*?}", m =>
        {

            var values = m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 2).Split(',');
            return values.ElementAt(random.Next(values.Length));
        });

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Be careful though about embedded `{{}}`. If you expect that scenario to happen, you might want to:

1. Write your own parsing engine,
2. Or use [Balancing Group Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed and such little code, thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
string myString = "Hello {you,uyo,u}, whats up?";

string[] stringList = myString.Split('{');
string before = stringList[0];

stringList = stringList[1].Split('}');
string after = stringList[1];

stringList = stringList[0].Split(',');



foreach (string s in stringList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(before+" "+s+""+after);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
Hello you, whats up?
Hello uyo, whats up?
Hello u, whats up?
```

To make it choose only the random word:

```
Random rand = new Random();

int i = rand.Next(stringList.Length);

Console.WriteLine(before + " " + stringList[i] + "" + after);
```

This solution assumes that you can put the brackets only **once** in the input string. But you could easily edit/improve it to handle more. For example you could first count the brackets in the string and depending on it create a foreach to retrive all the possible values.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally, use indexOf**

Lots of ways to do this, however you really need to use indexOf.

```
int openBrace = originalString.indexOf("{");
```

if openBrace is -1, then it wasn't found. If you wan't to process through all braces, then you're going to need to use an additional parameter option.

```
int closingBrace = 0;
int openBrace = 0;
//Loop forever, break logic is inside
while (true) {
    openBrace = originalString.indexOf("{", closingBrace);
    if (openBrace == -1) break;
    closingBrace = originalString.indexOf("}", openBrace);
    if (closingBrace == -1) closingBrace = originalString.Length;

    openBrace++; //Doing this, makes the next statement look nice
    string BraceContents = originalString.SubString(openBrace, closingBrace - openBrace);
}
```

(Possibly bugs in there, so let me know if you need help improving it)

I hope you get the idea. You current process of using split and contains is very limited.

**Suggested Script Parsing Architecture**

However, for performance, and simplicity of your whole system of processing a script, you may want to process the originalString one character at a time, and output to a StringBuilder.

**Generally, use indexOf**

Lots of ways to do this, however you really need to use indexOf.

```
int openBrace = originalString.indexOf("{");
```

if openBrace is -1, then it wasn't found. If you wan't to process through all braces, then you're going to need to use an additional parameter option.

```
int closingBrace = 0;
int openBrace = 0;
//Loop forever, break logic is inside
while (true) {
    openBrace = originalString.indexOf("{", closingBrace);
    if (openBrace == -1) break;
    closingBrace = originalString.indexOf("}", openBrace);
    if (closingBrace == -1) closingBrace = originalString.Length;

    openBrace++; //Doing this, makes the next statement look nice
    string BraceContents = originalString.SubString(openBrace, closingBrace - openBrace);
}
```

(Possibly bugs in there, so let me know if you need help improving it)

I hope you get the idea. You current process of using split and contains is very limited.

**Suggested Script Parsing Architecture**

However, for performance, and simplicity of your whole system of processing a script, you may want to process the originalString one character at a time, and output to a StringBuilder.

```
class ScriptParser
{
    //Declare as member variables, to make sub-function calls simpler (not need to have "ref i", for example)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    string scriptString;

    public string Parse(string input)
    {
        scriptString = input; //Share across object

        //Loop through each character one at a time once
        for (i = 0; i < scriptString.Length; i++)
        {
            //I suggest naming your conditions like this, especially if you're going to have more types of commands, and escape sequences in the future.
            bool isRandomCommand = (scriptString[i] == '{'); //What you have described
            bool isSomeOtherCommand = (scriptString[i] == '['); //Dummy
            bool isCommand = isRandomCommand || isSomeOtherCommand; //For later, determines whether we continue, bypassing the direct copy-through default

            //Command processing
            if (isRandomCommand) //TODO: perhaps detect if the next character is double brace, in which case it's an escape sequence and we should output '{'
                ProcessRandomCommand(); //This function will automatically update i to the end of the brace
            else if (isSomeOtherCommand) //Dummy
                ProcessSomeOtherCommand(); //Dummy

            if (isCommand)
                continue; //The next character could be another {} section, so re-evaluate properly

            sb.Append(scriptString[i]); //Else, simply copy through
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    void ProcessRandomCommand()
    {
        //Find the closing brace
        int closingBrace = scriptString.IndexOf("}", i);
        if (closingBrace == -1)
            throw new Exception("Closing brace not found");

        i++; //Makes the next statement nicer
        string randomOptionsDeclaration = scriptString.SubString(i, closingBrace - i);
        i = closingBrace; //Not closingBrace+1, because the caller will continue, and the for loop will then increment i

        string[] randomOptions = randomOptionsDeclaration.Split(',');
        int randomIndex = 0; //TODO: Randomisation here

        sb.Append(randomOptions[randomIndex]);
    }
}
```